# Redshift: Sorting order breaks when used with DISTINCT clause

Tags: sql, sorting, amazon-redshift, distinct

I have data like below:

```
select study_id , updated_by ,created_at 
from my_table ps 
where study_id = '1';
```

[image]

I want sort the records in Descending order based on `created_at` and pick distinct `study_id` and `updated_by`.

I tried below:

I've ran into a weird issue here in `Redshift`. Please consider the below query:

```
select study_id , updated_by 
from my_table ps 
where study_id = '1' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC ;
```

This results in:

[image]

But I need to pick only `Distinct` records. So, I used this query:

```
select DISTINCT study_id , updated_by 
from my_table ps
where study_id = '1' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC ;
```

This results in:

[image]

As you can see, the record with `maya2` is now being shown as latest instead of `maya1`.

Why does the sorting breaks with `DISTINCT`? How can I fix this?

Comment: your are ordering using created_at not updated_by

Comment: Yes, I want to `order` based on `timestamp` column `created_at` only

Comment: so check the created_at column data for maya2 and maya1

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Have updated my question with more data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so in your data set only maya1 is duplicated and **maya1** holding the timestamp 7:31 and 7:29 but **maya2** is holding 7:30 , so when you are using distinct then query engine remove one maya1 which is holding 7:31 as a result maya2 is getting the top posintion

if you need latest then simply use max

```
select study_id , updated_by ,max(created_at) as created_at
from my_table ps
where study_id = '1' 
group by study_id , updated_by 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

if you need only study_id , updated_by  then use row_number()

```
select  select study_id , updated_by from
( select study_id , updated_by ,
   row_number() over(partition by study_id , updated_by     ORDER BY created_at DESC ) rn
    from my_table ps
    where study_id = '1' 
 ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Yes, understood. But, I was hoping to get the results in latest order. How do I drop older duplicate records?

Comment: simply use max()

Answer (score 2):

What is surprising is the fact that the statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT study_id , updated_by 
FROM my_table ps
WHERE study_id = '1' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC ;
```

works at all. It makes no sense to order a data set according to an attribute that does not exist in the data set.

If you're trying to achieve a functionality equivalent to PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` then Redshift probably doesn't have it so you'd have to do it differently, using a sub-query:

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT study_id, updated_by
        , max(created_at) created_at -- Or min(created_at) - whatever you need
   FROM my_table ps
   WHERE study_id = '1' 
   GROUP BY study_id, updated_by
)
SELECT study_id, pudated_by
FROM t
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting didn't break.  As Zaynul pointed out you are ordering on created_at DESC (and we don't see that data in your example) so whatever value is in the <1, maya2> row is greater than the created_at values in the other rows.

After the updated data: you have two rows with maya1, one with created_at < the maya2 row timestamp and 1 with created_at timestamp > the maya2 row timestamp.

The DISTINCT operation selected the row with the timestamp > the maya2 row.  The DISTINCT operation will non-deterministically select a row from the set with the same keys of interest (<study_id, updated_by>).

Comment: I've updated the question with more data, please have a look.